# C programing with arrays argument of type "struct student" is incompatible with parameter of type "struct student *" error

Tags: c, arrays, function

Hi I am making this program for a c class and I have racked my brain on this as much as i can im coming here because I cant go to my teacher or the tutoring department as they are not available when I'm not working.

I am having a problem with theses two functions

```
void examination_seating_init(int rowNum, int columnNum, struct examination_seating* t)
{
    struct student* placeholder;
    for (int row = 0; row < columnNum; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < rowNum; col++) {
            *placeholder = t->seating[row][col];
            student_init_default(placeholder);
        }
    }
}

void examination_seating_to_string(struct examination_seating* t)
{
    char seatingchart = "The current seating: \n --------------------\n";
    struct student *temp;
    for (int row = 0; row < sizeof t->seating; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < sizeof t->seating[0]; col++) {
            if (col == sizeof t->seating[0] - 1) {
                *temp = t->seating[row][col];
                student_to_string(temp);
                seatingchart = ("%c %c \n", seatingchart, temp);
            }
            else {
                    *temp = t->seating[row][col];
                    student_to_string(temp);
                    seatingchart = ("%c %c ", seatingchart, temp);
            }

        }
    }
    printf("%c", seatingchart);
}
```

Both of these are giving me an uninitialized local variable used error im not sure if there's a better way to do what im trying to do or what specifically im doing wrong any help would be amazing I have included my full program here for reference.

I've also tried this

```
{
    for (int row = 0; row < columnNum; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < rowNum; col++) {
            student_init_default(t->seating[row][col]);
        }
    }
}
```

but that gives me an argument of type "struct student" is incompatible with parameter of type "struct student *" error

```
    #pragma warning(disable : 4996)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
    char last_name[30];
    char first_name[30];
};
struct examination_seating {
    struct student** seating;
};
void student_init_default(struct student* p)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof p; ++i) {
        p->first_name[i] = '###';
        p->last_name[i] = '###';
    }
}
void student_init(struct student* p, char* info)
{
    char* names;
    names = strtok(info, "/");
    while (names != NULL)
    {
        p = names;
        names = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
}

void student_to_string(struct student* p)
{
    char initials = "";
    initials = ("%c.%c", p->first_name[0], p->last_name[0]);
    return initials;
}

void examination_seating_init(int rowNum, int columnNum, struct examination_seating* t)
{
    struct student* placeholder;
    for (int row = 0; row < columnNum; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < rowNum; col++) {
            *placeholder = t->seating[row][col];
            student_init_default(placeholder);
        }
    }
}

int assign_student_at(int row, int col, struct examination_seating* t, struct student* p)
{
    if (strcmp(t->seating[row][col].first_name, "###"))
    {
        t->seating[row][col] = *p;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int check_boundaries(int row, int col, struct examination_seating* t)
{
    if (sizeof t->seating > 0 | t->seating < row)
        if (sizeof t->seating[0] > 0 | t->seating[0] < col)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;

        }
}

void examination_seating_to_string(struct examination_seating* t)
{
    char seatingchart = "The current seating: \n --------------------\n";
    struct student *temp;
    for (int row = 0; row < sizeof t->seating; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < sizeof t->seating[0]; col++) {
            if (col == sizeof t->seating[0] - 1) {
                *temp = t->seating[row][col];
                student_to_string(temp);
                seatingchart = ("%c %c \n", seatingchart, temp);
            }
            else {
                    *temp = t->seating[row][col];
                    student_to_string(temp);
                    seatingchart = ("%c %c ", seatingchart, temp);
            }

        }
    }
    printf("%c", seatingchart);
}

void main() {
    struct examination_seating examination_seating;
    struct student temp_student;
    int row, col, rowNum, columnNum;
    char student_info[30];
    // Ask a user to enter a number of rows for a examination seating
    printf("Please enter a number of rows for a examination seating.");
    scanf("%d", &rowNum);
    // Ask a user to enter a number of columns for a examination seating
    printf("Please enter a number of columns for a examination seating.");
    scanf("%d", &columnNum);
    // examination_seating
    examination_seating_init(rowNum, columnNum, &examination_seating);
    printf("Please enter a student information or enter \"Q\" to quit.");
    /*** reading a student's information ***/
    scanf("%s", student_info);
    /* we will read line by line **/
    while (1 /* change this condition*/) {
        printf("\nA student information is read.");
        // printing information.
        printf("%s", student_info);
        // student
        student_init(&temp_student, student_info);
        // Ask a user to decide where to seat a student by asking
        // for row and column of a seat
        printf("Please enter a row number where the student wants to sit.");
        scanf("%d", &row);
        printf("Please enter a column number where the student wants to sit.");
        scanf("%d", &col);
        // Checking if the row number and column number are valid
        // (exist in the examination that we created.)
        if (check_boundaries(row, col, &examination_seating) == 0) {
            printf("\nrow or column number is not valid.");
            printf("A student %s %s is not assigned a seat.", temp_student.first_name, temp_student.last_name);
        }
        else {
            // Assigning a seat for a student
            if (assign_student_at(row, col, &examination_seating, &temp_student) == 1) {
                printf("\nThe seat at row %d and column %d is assigned to the student", row, col);
                student_to_string(&temp_student);
                examination_seating_to_string(&examination_seating);
            }
            else {
                printf("\nThe seat at row %d and column %d is taken.", row, col);
            }
        }
        // Read the next studentInfo
        printf("Please enter a student information or enter \"Q\" to quit.");
        /*** reading a student's information ***/
        scanf("%s", student_info);
    }
}
```

Comment: "giving me an uninitialized local variable" That error is very clear. `*placeholder` is dereferncing that variable but that variable has never been set.

Comment: Try: `student_init_default(&t->seating[row][col]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how pointers work in c.
I would start here: https://computer.howstuffworks.com/c20.htm it goes on for several pages (hit next).
Now to the problem at hand, **you must allocate the space you are pointing at.**
See here how to do so: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/
Also some info about strings in c: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-strings
I have fixed the issues you've asked about (and some others) however there are probably more issues in the code.
I recommend you learn more about pointers, allocation and strings in c.
For one, char is not a string, and char * must be allocated. If it is allocated in a function and returned (like in student_to_string) you should allocate it dynamicly or outside the function (like I did).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
    char last_name[30];
    char first_name[30];
};
struct examination_seating {
    struct student** seating;
};
void student_init_default(struct student* p)
{
    strcpy(p->first_name, "###");
    strcpy(p->last_name, "###");
}
void student_init(struct student* p, char* info)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char * current = p->first_name;
    while (info[i] != 0)
    {
        if (info[i] == '/')
        {
            current[j]=0;
            current = p->last_name;
            j=0;
        }
        else {
            current[j] = info[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    current[j]=0;
}

void student_to_string(struct student* p, char * initials)
{
    sprintf(initials, "%c.%c", p->first_name[0], p->last_name[0]);
}

void examination_seating_init(int rowNum, int columnNum, struct examination_seating* t)
{
    t->seating = malloc(rowNum * sizeof(struct student *)); 
    for (int row = 0; row < columnNum; row++) {
        t->seating[row] = malloc(columnNum* sizeof(struct student));
        for (int col = 0; col < rowNum; col++) {
            student_init_default(&(t->seating[row][col]));
        }
    }
}

int assign_student_at(int row, int col, struct examination_seating* t, struct student* p)
{
    if (!strcmp(t->seating[row][col].first_name, "###"))
    {
        strcpy(t->seating[row][col].first_name, p->first_name);
        strcpy(t->seating[row][col].last_name, p->last_name);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int check_boundaries(int row, int rowNum, int col, int colNum)
{
    if (row > 0 | row < rowNum)
        if (sizeof col > 0 | col < colNum)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;

        }
}

void examination_seating_to_string(struct examination_seating* t)
{
    char seatingchart[] = "The current seating: \n --------------------\n";
    struct student *temp;
    char initials[4];
    for (int row = 0; row < sizeof t->seating; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < sizeof t->seating[0]; col++) {
            if (col == sizeof t->seating[0] - 1) {
                student_to_string(&t->seating[row][col], initials);
                sprintf(seatingchart,"%s %s \n", seatingchart, initials);
            }
            else {
                    student_to_string(&t->seating[row][col], initials);
                    sprintf(seatingchart,"%s %s ", seatingchart, initials);
            }

        }
    }
    printf("%s", seatingchart);
}

void main() {
    struct examination_seating examination_seating;
    struct student temp_student;
    int row, col, rowNum, columnNum;
    char student_info[30];
    char initials[4];
    // Ask a user to enter a number of rows for a examination seating
    printf("Please enter a number of rows for a examination seating.");
    scanf("%d", &rowNum);
    // Ask a user to enter a number of columns for a examination seating
    printf("Please enter a number of columns for a examination seating.");
    scanf("%d", &columnNum);
    // examination_seating
    examination_seating_init(rowNum, columnNum, &examination_seating);
    printf("Please enter a student information or enter \"Q\" to quit.");
    /*** reading a student's information ***/
    scanf("%s", student_info);
    /* we will read line by line **/
    while (1 /* change this condition*/) {
        printf("\nA student information is read.");
        // printing information.
        printf("%s", student_info);
        // student
        student_init(&temp_student, student_info);
        // Ask a user to decide where to seat a student by asking
        // for row and column of a seat
        printf("Please enter a row number where the student wants to sit.");
        scanf("%d", &row);
        printf("Please enter a column number where the student wants to sit.");
        scanf("%d", &col);
        // Checking if the row number and column number are valid
        // (exist in the examination that we created.)
        if (check_boundaries(row, rowNum, col, columnNum) == 0) {
            printf("\nrow or column number is not valid.");
            printf("A student %s %s is not assigned a seat.", temp_student.first_name, temp_student.last_name);
        }
        else {
            // Assigning a seat for a student
            if (assign_student_at(row, col, &examination_seating, &temp_student) == 1) {
                printf("\nThe seat at row %d and column %d is assigned to the student", row, col);
                student_to_string(&temp_student, initials);
                examination_seating_to_string(&examination_seating);
            }
            else {
                printf("\nThe seat at row %d and column %d is taken.", row, col);
            }
        }
        // Read the next studentInfo
        printf("Please enter a student information or enter \"Q\" to quit.");
        /*** reading a student's information ***/
        scanf("%s", student_info);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thnak you! Thank you! You are absolutely correct I have been struggling with pointers. All of my experience in programing comes form .net with C# code behind and the java I took in my last two classes. C has been a struggle for me the documents you gave me have been  great if anyone comes here with similar problems read those pages they are a wealth of knowledge and a lot better worded then the book for the class